# picture as a background of shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, background, shinydashboard

I would like to change background in my shiny dashboard App. I wound in internet function setBackgroundImage (https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/setBackgroundImage.html). The problem is that I don't know were I should put that function in my app. In example is classic app, not dashboard.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    setBackgroundImage(src = "http://wallpics4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/470318.jpg")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also it is possible to put leaflet map as a background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `tags$img()`, and specifying position attribute to absolute. Note that img tag have to be placed as first in `dashboardBody`:

```
...
  dashboardBody(
    tags$img(
      src = "http://wallpics4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/470318.jpg",
      style = 'position: absolute'
    ),
    ...
  )
...
```

It also accepts `width` and `height` parameters. You can also position your image with `hspace` and `vspace` parameters.

Comment: but its like element, I would like to have picture as a background and have possibility to put elements (like boxes) on it.

Comment: @dasti74 I've edited my answer. Check it and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: it works, thanks! I have one more question. Do you know if it is possible to use leaflet map as a background? In other words, instead of putting the link in, place the leafletoutput object

Comment: You can't put leafletoutput object in img tag for sure. But I think you can wrap it with simple `div` and add `style = 'position: absolute'`.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. You have to do this with css.  1. Place `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css"))` as first in `dashboardBody`.  2. Place `leafletOutput('myMap')` as second in `dashboardBody`.  3. Create folder named `www` in the same directory as your shiny app file.  4. Create `style.css` file with the following content: `#myMap {
  position: absolute;
}` in the `www` folder.  Everything you will put after `leafletOutput` will be placed on the map.

Comment: you are awesome!

Comment: Thanks :D I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Now there is also the possibility to add `shinydashboard = TRUE` to the `setBackgroundImage` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    setBackgroundImage(
      src = "https://www.fillmurray.com/1920/1080",
      shinydashboard = TRUE
    )
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does it support `gifs`? Also can I use it it with `navbarPage` instead of `dashboardPage`?